# Where can I find debug builds of the WebKit framework for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, debugging, webkit, symbols

I'm troubleshooting a crash that's happening deep in the WebKit framework (specifically in `WebCore.framework`). The cause of the crash is a known bug in WebKit. In order to work around it, I need to be able to figure out what DOM element WebKit is working with when it crashes. For that I need to inspect the local and stack variables in WebKit at the time of the crash.

I have a core dump, but of course no debug symbol table for WebKit.

**Are these available anywhere?**

I found the [WebKit nightly builds](http://nightly.webkit.org/) page, but those appear to be released builds stripped of debug information,

My fallback plan is to download WebKit sources and [build them myself with debug switches](http://www.webkit.org/building/build.html), but it'd be amazing if those debug binaries were already archived somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple technical support; they told me that no symbols for the Mountain Lion shipping version of `WebCore.framework` were available anywhere. Apple appears to have stopped providing debug libraries after OS X 10.5.

We wound up working around the problem by using `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html)) to load a non-buggy version of WebKit on the customer's machine.